# how to install python and node.js using putty?

Tags: python-2.7

when I enter `python -V` then it shows `python 2.4.3.`
but I want to change `python 2.4.3` to `python 2.7.`
if you have any process then give me a complete process>>>>>>>-bash-3.2$ ./configure

```
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux2
checking EXTRAPLATDIR...
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... i686
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/var/chroot/home/content/33/11169633/python/Python-2.6.7':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

See `config.log` for more details.

Comment: where are you trying to do this?  I.e. which distribution of linux

Comment: Make sure you have a C compiler on the remote host. The fact that you're using Putty is irrelevant, what matters is the OS on the remote.

Answer (score 1):

Installing gcc package solved my problem.

```
    yum install gcc
```